# Eloquent - Login and keep User logged in | laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, authentication, eloquent

How do you keep a User logged in without using the Auth facade?
I managed to check for matched credentials but I do not know how to keep the User logged in.. Do I just set a session entry with the ID of the logged in user?

**Here is the function that handles the credentials check**

```
public function postLogin(Request $request) {
        $pushUser = \App\PushUser::where([
            'email' => $request->useremail,
            'password' => $request->userpassword
            ])->first();

        if(!$pushUser) {
            return Redirect::back(); // No such user in database, go back to login route
        }
        // Login user, make sure he stays logged in until he loggs out or the session expires
        return Redirect::route('home'); // Redirect to home route
    }
```

Please excuse me for this stupid question, I'm really new to website authentication.. I'd just place a session entry with the ID of the logged in user, but this seem too dangerous, because I fear that someone cracks the session / cookie ID..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in your table migration

```
$table->rememberToken();
```

Then add this in your model

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class PushUser extends Authenticatable {
```

This will add a `remember_token` string field which laravel uses to remember a logged in user. Then in your `postLogin` method do this

```
\Auth::login($pushUser, true);
```

Edit `auth.php` config file to change the default users model.

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\PushUser::class,
    ],
```

Comment: This worked for me, except that the table "users" does not exist in my db. My table is "push_users". This is why I didnt wanted to use Auth:: at all.

I wanted to create my own authentication system, so that I know exactly, what is done where and how.. Now I am using the Auth::login function and dont even know what happens at all..

Comment: The table name of the users doesn't matter. You can use any table to login and use the built in auth.

Comment: The Auth::login method just sets the passed user object as the authenticated user and creates the session information.

Comment: The problem is, it does matter which table I use, because the Auth::login checks for users in the "users" table. `Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'mydb.users' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `users` where `id` = 3 limit 1)`

Comment: Goto the auth.php in your config file and edit the `'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],
` to your model and it should work. Simple as that

Answer (score 1):

I think you're asking about how to authenticate a user without using Laravel `attempt()` method. You can login user manually:

```
Auth::login($user, true);
```

> If you need to log an existing user instance into your application, you may call the `login` method with the user instance.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#other-authentication-methods

But keeping unencrypted passwords is a terrible idea. Avoid this.

Comment: You should add a note reminding the user to add the `remember_token` field to the table for this to work. `$table->rememberToken();`

Comment: After writing `Auth::login($pushUser, true);` I get the following error `Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must be an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, instance of App\PushUser given, called in D:\xampp\htdocs\myProject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager.php on line 294`

Comment: @Dean your class should extend `Authenticable` class, so do something like this if you didn't done it yet: `use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticable; class PushUser extends Authenticable`. You can look at an example in default `User` model created by Laravel.